# Eosio account create problem

Tags: cleos

cleos create account eosio mark prikey1 prikey2
if i run this it will show error
Whether I must import key to default wallet or to eosio etc?
Thanks

Comment: What error is it showing?

Answer (score 0):

To create an account, you must first have imported the eosio key.  This key comes by default to all new installs and it's the same for everyone (at least at the time of this posting..).  To import the key you must have created a wallet.

```
cleos wallet create --to-console
```

Copy password here, you will need it to unlock wallet.

```
cleos wallet unlock

cleos wallet import --private-key 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
```

Then you need to import the private key for your account you want to create:

`cleos create key --to-console` will give you a new key for your mark account

Then `cleos wallet import --private-key [THAT NEW KEY]`

Then you should be good to:

`cleos create account eosio mark [OWNER] [ACTIVE] -p eosio`

Link to docs covering all the steps: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets

Comment: thanks
i do not need to import the private key for eosio manually？